# iOS 16: title of UINavigationBar disappears

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

In my app, I used UIViewController as a bottom sheet. BottomSheet consists of NavigationBar(title and close button) and ScrollView(for contentView). Until iOS 16, I had no problems with the navigationBar's title. But with iOS 16, the title appears for a very short time and disappears. I don't think the problem is with Constraints.

There is probably a point that I missed in the updates that come with iOS 16.

Thank you in advance for your interest and answers.

Comment: Can you add some code to clarify this question? If you ever try simplify your code to another empty project to confirm this question just appear due to iOS 16?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I will try to make my question more concrete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I was looking for a solution to my problem, with the help of a friend, I learned that the problem was caused by Apple.

The subject has been discussed on Developer Forum website. Apple is solving the problem with iOS 16.1.

I tested it with iOS 16.1 and I can confirm that the issue is resolved.

[Developer Forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/713424)